# PHP multiplication string

Tags: php, string, volume, multiplication, cubic

I have just begun learning PHP, and I have been working on a practice page for finding the cubic volume of a cube.  The information is taken from submissions on an html form and I have written the code for taken the submitted information as the variables but I am not entirely sure how to set up the result.

here is my code so far

```
<?php
  #Script calculates cubic volume 

  $length=$_POST["length"];

  $width=$_POST["width"];

  $height=$_POST["height"];

  $result=
```

I am just not sure how to format the $result line so that it will properly multiply the length, width, and height.
I also apologize for such a beginner question, I just couldn't find the answer at other sources.

Comment: To multiply, it's the Asterisk `*` which is the odd one Thankfully,  Divide `\``  Add '+' and Subtract `-`  are at least close to what we humans are used to.

Comment: SO is not a PHP chapter 1 page 1 paragraph 1 tutorial site. There is a PHP manual available to all [Here is book 1 page 1 chanper 1 to get you started](http://php.net/docs.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the values coming from the POST array are all strings, it's better to manually cast them to ints (or floats, if need be) instead of relying on PHP's automatic type casting.

```
$result = (int)$length * (int)$width * (int)$height;  
print $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result=  $length * $height * $width;
echo $result;
```

Comment: Ah so it was actually quite a simple line then. Thank you very much!

Comment: This will certainly work and answers the question, but such a form, with no error checking on input does create some security concerns.. Adding something like `if(is_numeric($_POST['length'])){$length= $_POST['length'];}`  would add some measure of security. TLDR Never trust end user input. Always assume it's a hack attempt

Comment: I will take note of what you said about error checking as I move forward. Thank you!